# EditText changing WebView page on separate xml files?

Tags: java, android, xml, browser, webview

I am developing an Android web browser, using the libraries ActionbarSherlock and SlidingMenu, I have an EditText as my URL bar, and because its a sliding menu it requires its own .xml file, how can I force my "Go" button to change webpage on another .xml file?

If you need it, here is my code for the sliding menu's .xml~

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public EditText iText;
public WebView iWeb;

public class LeftMenu extends Home_View implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.left_slide);

        iText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.urlText);
        Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bGo);
        go.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bGo:
            String page = iText.getText().toString();
            iWeb.loadUrl(page);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have my WebView on a separate .xml as my EditText, I want the EditText to change the webpage loding on the WebView. If that makes more sense. @Janmejoy